# Java Dropwizard initialize ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, dropwizard

Let's say I have a custom ConstraintValidator:

```
public class FooValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidFoo, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(final ValidFoo foo) {
        // No-op
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String foo, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to initialize this class by passing some configuration from the `ServiceConfiguration` in Dropwizard `run` or `initialize`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's worth noting that the upcoming Dropwizard 2.0.0 release has [built in support for this](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/2432)

---

For now, the process is a bit involved. You basically want to re-bootstrap the Hibernate validation but with a custom constraint validator factory that would support injection.

It's gonna involve about 4 custom classes, so bear with me. Here goes:

First, we start by registering a custom feature to wrap this functionality, into our `Application` class:

```
public void run(MainConfiguration config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  // ...
  environment.jersey().register(InjectingValidationFeature.class);
}
```

Now we define the feature: `InjectingValidationFeature` - it basically registers our custom implementations within the service container:

```
public class InjectingValidationFeature implements Feature {

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
    context.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        bindFactory(ValidatorFactory.class).to(Validator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(InjectingConfiguredValidator.class).to(ConfiguredValidator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.class).to(ConstraintValidatorFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
      }
    });

    return true;
  }
}
```

Now we define those classes that we are registering above. Let's start with the core piece, the `InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory` which is what Hibernate Validator will actually use to create the constraint validators. Note that because we are registering them in the container, we can actually start injecting stuff already, here is our custom `ConstraintValidatorFactory` making use of the service locator to make dependency injection possible:

```
public class InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {

  private final ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

  @Inject
  public InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
    this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
    return this.serviceLocator.createAndInitialize(key);
  }

  @Override
  public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
    this.serviceLocator.preDestroy(instance);
  }
}
```

Now our factory for the central `javax.validation.Validator` interface:

```
public class ValidatorFactory implements Factory<Validator> {

  private final ConstraintValidatorFactory constraintValidatorFactory;

  @Inject
  public ValidatorFactory(ConstraintValidatorFactory constraintValidatorFactory) {
    this.constraintValidatorFactory = constraintValidatorFactory;
  }

  @Override
  public Validator provide() {
    return Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().constraintValidatorFactory(
        this.constraintValidatorFactory).buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose(Validator instance) {
    // Nothing
  }
}
```

And finally, our `InjectingConfiguredValidator`, notice how it's just using `DropwizardConfiguredValidator` but with an `@Inject` which would allow us to receive the validator from our `ValidatorFactory` above:

```
public class InjectingConfiguredValidator extends DropwizardConfiguredValidator {
  @Inject
  public InjectingConfiguredValidator(Validator validator) {
    super(validator);
  }
}
```

That's it. With the above, we managed to both register an injection-aware `Validator` with Jersey and also into our service container so you can also `@Inject Validator` anywhere and use it however you like.